# Save all files in Jupyter notebook with js api

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a front end project written in typescript React framework and I am looking for saving all `ipynub` files.

I want to click on a button that will call to jupyter API to save all `ipynub` files.
Is there a way to trigger save all as `PUT` or `POST` request as JS?